# How to force jQuery to issue GET request to server to refresh cached resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

There are a lot of answers all around the web how to prevent jQuery AJAX requests from being cached. **This is not what I'm trying to do.**

I need the AJAX request to be returned from the cache based on condition in my code. That is, when the request is issued during page load, it is completely ok to return cached response (in fact that is the intention). But when the user clicks a button, I need the same request to be refreshed from the server.

I know that I can do this by setting `cache: false` option in jQuery, but this will just request the data with a different URL thus not refreshing the response in the cache and during the next page load the request with `cache: true` will return the obsolete data.

I tried adding a `Cache-Control` header to the request but that does not have effect at least in IE10.

```
$.ajax({
    url: Configuration.ApiRootUri + "Notifications",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { 'Cache-Control': refreshCache ? 'no-cache' : 'private' },
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

Is it possible at all to force the browser to refresh a cached resource from script?

Answer (score 1):

(note: rewritten after discussion in the comments)

A solution would be to store the response from the server in the localstorage and load it at page load if it does exists.

This avoid completely the request made to the server at start and act like a cache, but in the browser.

Here's a pseudo-algo example :

```
function loadRequest(){
    Call Ajax request
        On success, store the result in the localstorage, call updateHtml(result);
}

function updateHtml(data) {
    Update the specific html (list, view, etc) with the data
}

$('#mybutton').on ('click', loadRequest);

$(function() {
    Check if the data in the localstorage exists
        if exists, call updateHtml(localstorage.value);
        else call loadRequest 
});
```

That's it!

Comment: This does not solve the issue. 1) I need the cache to be in the browser to remove the request to the server. 2) Server cache cannot be used - too many concurrent users plus web farm. 3) I need the browser cache to be according to the server cache-control response headers. 4) your proposal to send a user session key with the request - this will result in different URL for page load and refresh thus the next page load will not use the refreshed values.

Comment: As I stated, the cache is in the browser, but this only works if this browser (i.e. the same user, on the same computer with the same browser) has already made the request. Since you don't clearly indicate if you would like to use the cache or if you absolutely need to use the cache, I suggested both. The request will always be made to the server but the cache will be used only if the headers returned FROM the server are the same as when the first request was made.

Comment: What I am looking for is to avoid the request going out to the server on page load but to always send it when the user clicks the button. I know that I can add `Must-Revalidate` header to the response and the browser will now always request the resource and the server will then be able to respond with HTTP status code 304 but in my case the server will not know if the data is current (I don't have a distributed cache in my solution and cost of refreshing the data is much larger than sending it over the wire).

Comment: And what about storing the last updated value in the localstorage ? When you load the page, you load the data in the localstorage if it exists, if not you request the server (first time, so not cached). And when the user click on the button, you only request the server, and store the result in the localstorage => cached.

Comment: @CyrilN. i was just writing quite similar comment, using persistent storage client side to get specific URL request like: `"myUrl.com?v="+localStorageValue` Will this work? Need testing i think

Comment: I don't get it. The idea you suggest (`"myUrl.com?v="+localStorageValue`) is the same than using a key stored in the session and sent to the url on page load. No, what I'm suggesting here is to avoid completely to query the server. You store the response in the localstorage, and only load it at load page if it does exists.

Comment: If you found the answer of your question, I'm glad I could've helped.